# why doesnt my powershell script compare dates correctly?

Tags: powershell

trying to compare dates if its todate or greater then do not enable, if its less then or equal to today, enable account based on the description

[image]

```
    $newemployees = Get-aduser -Filter * -Properties whencreated, Description, Samaccountname | Where-Object {$_.whenCreated -gt $Datecutoff}  `
| Select-Object Description, enabled, Samaccountname | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq $False}
$DateCutOff=(Get-Date).AddDays(-14)

$lastpasstest = Get-ADUser -Identity lastpasstest -Properties Description, Samaccountname | Select-Object Description, enabled, Samaccountname

$today = Get-Date -format MM/dd/yyyy
Write-Output "todays Date: $today"

$newpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "apasswordwemightuse!" -AsPlainText –Force

ForEach ( $user in $newemployees ) {
    if ($user.description -ge $today)
    {
    Write-Output "Start Date: $($user.description)"
    Write-Output "Users will be enabled on their start date: $($user.SamAccountName)"
    } 
    if ($user.description -le $today) {
     Write-Output "Enabling User: $($user.SamAccountName) $($user.description)"
     $user.SamAccountName | Enable-ADAccount 
     Set-ADAccountPassword $user -NewPassword $newpwd -Reset
     Set-ADuser $user -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried if and then just an else, but it did the same output

Comment: Hmmmm ... you use `$DateCutOff` before you define it.  And in your loop you comparing the desciption attribute with a string representive of a DateTime object. What is it actually what you're trying to do? Please add an explanation to your question.

Comment: the datecutoff is just searching for new accounts created in less then two weeks, then i want to enable accounts if the account is equal to today (itll run as a task every morning at 7:30) so that we can automate enabling of accounts

Comment: Please add this to your question - not as comment!  But still - you define `$DateCutOff` **after** you use it. That cannot work

Comment: Note that in the loop you're comparing strings not dates.

Comment: do you meean todays date vs description field?

Comment: Yep.  For example this fails:  `'01/01/2021' -gt '02/01/2020'`.  Usually people put the year first in strings they want to sort.

Comment: that's why the international datetime format [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) uses yyyy/mm/dd so computers can sort it as string properly. But why on earth do you use `Get-Date -format` which returns a string? `Get-Date` returns a DateTime object which can be compared and operated on correctly. Just use that one without `-format` and only format the object when printing

Comment: so how do i compare that if i have text in my description field i need to compare to?

Comment: DateTime already has all the necessary operators, just them compare normally

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Putting a `[datetime]` on the left side of the operand should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things here, so let's go over them one at a time, but first for the TLDR folks: The answer to your original question is that you're comparing strings. The `$User.description` value is a string, and you converted that date to a string for `$today` when you formatted it. In order to compare dates you would need the value type on the left of the operator to be a `[datetime]` object.

Now let's get down to the business of really fixing this here.

The first issue I see is that you define `$DateCutOff` in line 3 after you try to use it in a comparison in line 1. So we move line 3 to the top, simple enough.

Next you get all of the users in AD, then whittle them down with `Where-Object` statements. That's asking for a lot, it is far better to use the `-Filter` parameter to only ask AD for the users you want. Let's convert the lines that you query AD to do that with this:

```
$DateCutOff = (get-date).AddDays(-14)
$newemployees = Get-aduser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false -and whenCreated -gt $DateCutOff} -Properties whencreated, Description, Samaccountname | 
    Select-Object Description, enabled, Samaccountname
```

That should only get the users that you want from AD, which should result in fewer timeouts and faster responses in general.

Then we have a line that appears to serve no purpose so I'm skipping it. Moving down to when you define `$today`. You use the `-f` parameter, which is used to format the date as a string. In order to keep it a date you would need to leave that part off. If you want it formatted you can always do that later.

```
$today = get-date
```

Personally, and this is my preference, I skip defining things like that and just use `[datetime]::today` in their place. That's just me, but I thought I'd put it in here in case you wanted to do so as well.

Now, because we changed that to a date, your `write-output` line won't look the same. For that matter, using `Write-Output` is redundant. Anything not otherwise explicitly redirected is sent to the output. So we can just change that to this:

```
"todays Date: {0}" -f $today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

After that you define the password, which is in plain text, and in general is a no-no, but it's functional so I'll leave it alone.

```
$newpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "apasswordwemightuse!" -AsPlainText –Force
```

Now we get to the loop where you check if users should be enabled. I mentioned above that you are comparing strings, but it is worth noting that when it comes to comparisons PowerShell looks at the value on the left's type and tries to convert the value on the right to match. So really the simplest way to fix your original script is to type cast the description as a `[datetime]` object like `If([datetime]($user.description) -gt $today){`, but that seems dirty to me since it would then have to convert `$today` to a datetime each time as well as the description. Better to have at least one be a datetime already and work from there. So what I would do is put today's datetime object first, and compare the description to that, like this:

```
ForEach ( $user in $newemployees ) {
    if ([datetime]::today -lt $user.description)
```

Beyond that you run users through `If($user.description -ge $today)` and `If($user.description -le $today)`, but really it's going to be one or the other, so you could just do the second part as an `else` clause. That said, here's what I'd have done:

```
ForEach ( $user in $newemployees ) {
    if ([datetime]::today -lt $user.description)
    {
        "Start Date: $($user.description)"
        "Users will be enabled on their start date: $($user.SamAccountName)"
    } 
    else
    {
        "Enabling User: $($user.SamAccountName) $($user.description)"
        $user.SamAccountName | Enable-ADAccount 
        Set-ADAccountPassword $user -NewPassword $newpwd -Reset
        Set-ADuser $user -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True
    }
}
```

Lastly, you write a fair bit to screen. You might want to convert that to `write-verbose` so that it quietly runs, but if you need to keep a closer eye on things you can run it with the `-verbose` switch, or change your `$VerbosePreference` for the session.